# Guía para resolver problema "sencillo" en PHP

Tags: php, c++, c

Necesito de una mano amiga que me guíe en la resolución de un problema. Tengo demasiado tiempo intentando entender y lamentablemente no logro comprender cómo resolver dicho problema en este lenguaje, estoy realmente confundida porque estoy familiarizada con C/C++ pero cuando lo intento en PHP, no logro entender. Se supone que con dicho ejercicio debería ayudar de entender y relacionar diferentes sintaxis pero sin una explicación previa, relación entre variables de diferentes lenguajes, simplemente no logro entenderlo. No pido que me lo resuelvan, pero si pueden darme alguna explicación para poder relacionar los lenguajes (dado a que es el mismo problema para ambos lenguajes) para poder resolverlo y sobre todo entender qué estoy usando, qué estoy escribiendo, se los agradecería demasiado. Acá les dejo las herramientas.

**Ya resuelto en C**

```
/*2. Leer dos números si el primero es mayor realizar la suma //
de los dos números; si el segundo es mayor elevar al cuadrado cada número. Mostrar los 
resultados.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
int num1, num2, suma, A, B;

printf ("Conozcamos tus numeros\n");
printf ("Primer valor: ");
scanf ("%d", &num1);
printf ("Segundo Valor: ");
scanf ("%d", &num2);
if (num1 > num2){
    suma=num1+num2;
    printf ("La suma de tus numeros es: %d\n", suma);
}
else if (num2 > num1){
    A= pow(num1,2);
    B= pow(num2,2);
    printf ("El primer valor al cuadrado es: %d\n", A);
    printf ("El segundo valor al cuadrado es: %d\n", B);
}
else if (num1 == num2){
    printf ("Ambos numeros son iguales");
}
getch ();
return 0;
```

**Pseudocodigo**

```
 Variables: num1, num2, suma, A, B.
 Escribir: “Conozcamos tus números”.
 Escribir: “Primer número”.
 Leer: num1.
 Escribir: “Segundo número”.
 Leer: num2.
 Si: (num1 = num2).
 Escribir: Ambos números son iguales.
 Sino: (num1 > num2).
 Entonces: suma = num1 + num2.
 Escribir: “La suma de sus números es (suma)”.
 Sino: (num2 > num1).
 Entonces:
 A = 〖(num1)〗^2.
 B = 〖(num2)〗^2.
 Escribir: “El primer valor al cuadrado es (A)”.
 Escribir: “El segundo valor al cuadrado es (B)”.
 Finalizar.
```

Si me pueden guiar para resolverlo en php, se los agradecería un montón. Gracias!!

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y realiza el [tour], para que la comunidad pueda ayudar de manera mas efectiva debes indicar que has intentado aún cuando dichos intentos no funcionen así como dudas mas específicas.

Comment: En php las variables tienen el prefijo $ y no necesitas declarar el tipo. los printf lo cambias por print (o por echo). Concatenas con un punto: print("El primer valor al cuadrado es".$A); El pow lo puedes cambiar por una multiplicación $num1*$num1

Comment: [`$num1 = (int)readline('Ingresa número: ');`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readline.php) [`printf ("La suma de tus numeros es: %d\n", $suma);`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php) ,  [`$A= pow($num1,2);`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pow.php) el `\n` puede ser reemplazado por `PHP_EOL` así salta la línea correctamente según el sistema operativo `printf ("La suma de tus numeros es: %d" . PHP_EOL, $suma);`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a los comentarios, realmente me ayudaron muchísimo, estaba realmente estresada, y pensé que era muy diferente, resultó ser mucho más sencillo

Answer (score 1):

Sería bastante parecído, un poco más corto;

```
<?php //debe empezar por php
//no es necesario declarar las variables

echo "Conozcamos tus numeros\n"; //echo es más idiomatico que printf
echo "Primer valor: ";
$num1 = (int)fgets(STDIN);//hacer el cast a numero no es indispensable,
// pero quita el salto de linea que agrega fgets
echo "Segundo Valor:";
$num2 = (int)fgets(STDIN);
if ($num1 > $num2) {
   $suma = $num1 + $num2;
   echo "La suma de tus numeros es: $suma\n"; //Puedes poner las variables dentro de comillas dobles
} elseif ($num2 > $num1) {
   $A= $num1**2; //puedes pontenciar con **
   $B= $num2**2;
   echo "El primer valor al cuadrado es: $A\n";
   echo "El segundo valor al cuadrado es: $B\n";
} elseif ($num1 == $num2) {
   echo "Ambos numeros son iguales\n";
}
```

Comment: Si, al final investigando un poco báscamente reutilicé por así decirlo el códido de C, los comentarios anteriores me ayudaron mucho, y ahora con tu explicación, lo entiendo de una manera muchísimo mejor (cosa que no ocurre en la Uni)

Comment: oh! Si, con un formulario es diferente, lo que hice solo sirve para la linea de comando.

Comment: Lo hice como un formulario y básicamente es lo mismo que en código de C
`<?php

$num1 = $_POST["num1"];
$num2 = $_POST["num2"];
if ($num1 > $num2){
 $suma=$num1+$num2;
printf ("La suma de tus numeros es: %d\n", $suma);  
}
else if ($num1 < $num2){
 $A= pow($num1,2);
 $B= pow($num2,2);
 printf ("El primer valor al cuadrado es: %d\n", $A);
 printf ("El segundo valor al cuadrado es: %d\n", $B);
}
if ($num1 == $num2) {
 printf ("Los número son iguales");
}
?>`

Comment: de igual manera, estoy muy agradecida, ya que me estás especificando alguna cosas que no podía relacionar